# request.data not always a queryDict

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-tests

Using a `PATCH` request on a `RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView` I receive the following in `RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView.update` when i run `print(request.data)`:

```
{'myVar': ''}
```

when running automated tests using django rest framework's [APIClient](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/testing/#apiclient) I get this:

```
<QueryDict: {'myVar': ['']}>
```

Why is this different?  What can i do to ensure consistency between my environments of test and dev?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be explicit that you're passing json, you can do this by either:

```
response = self.client.patch(self.url, json={'myVar': ''})
```

Or:

```
response = self.client.patch(self.url, {'myVar': ''}, format='json') # added , format='json'
```